# Understand the logic when overriding concrete method by abstract method

Tags: scala

First of all, I realize that it doesn't make much sense to override a concrete method in superclass by an abstract method in subclass. But... since in Scala it is actually possible to do this, I tried the following snippet, and the result's getting me confused.

## First scenario

- The concrete method to be overridden in super-super-class
- The abstract method is in super-class

```scala
class A {
  def x: String = "A"
}

abstract class B extends A {
  def x: String
}

class C extends B {
  def x: String = "C"
}
```

Executing the snippet above in scala REPL results in the follwing error:

```
  def x: String = "C"
      ^
<pastie>:10: error: `override` modifier required to override concrete member:
def x: String (defined in class A)
```

Now the question: Why it seems that the abstract method in class `B` was ignored? But `B.x` does actually have an effect if `C.x` is removed from definition. Because the following snippet doesn't compile either.

```scala
class A {
  def x: String = "A"
}

abstract class B extends A {
  def x: String
}

class C extends B
```

results in the following error

```
class C extends B
      ^
<pastie>:9: error: class C needs to be abstract. No implementation found in a subclass for deferred declaration
def x: String (defined in class B)
```

## Second scenario

- The concrete method to be overridden in super-class
- The abstract method is in trait

```scala
class A {
  def x: String = "A"
}

trait B {
  def x: String
}

class C extends A with B
```

Try instantiate `C`,

```
scala> (new C).x
val res0: String = A
```

It looks like the `B.x` abstract method just got ignored by compiler.

---

Update

In the first edition of my question, I idiotically forgot to extends `A` in the **second scenario**, which leads to an incorrect conclusion that class and trait behave differently in my examples. I sincerely apologize for my negligence.

Let me try to rephase my question:

In both the first and second scenario, what is the effect of the abstract `B.x` in the middle of class hierarchy?

As I understand it, by inheritance and method resolution order (MRO),

- in the first scenario `B.x` overrides `A.x` and `C.x` overrides `B.x`. Since `B.x` is abstract, when `C.x` implements `B.x`, it need not specify `override` modifier.
- in the second scenario, `B.x` overrides `A.x` and `C` didn't implement the abstract `B.x`. So `C` should be abstract and does not compile.

But it seems to me that the compiler just ignored the abstract method `B.x` in the middle of class hierarchy. Is this behavior defined somewhere in the language specification, or this is totally unintended and unexpected (and just a compiler bug)?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if the question is about the differences between Traits and Abstract Classes or about the differences between extends.

In the **First Scenario** you have `abstract class B extends A` in both cases but in the **Second Scenario** you have `trait A` and `trait B`. `B` is not extending `A`.
In fact, if you put `trait A extends B` in the **Second Scenario** it won't compile

In the second case of the **Second Scenario**, you are extending 2 different traits that have the same method, having `extends A with B` your class has the method x defined because the order matters when you extend from multiple traits. If you try to do it in the opposite order `extends B with A`, it won't compile

In other words:

Second Scenario - First case: Defining an abstract method doesn't need the override

Second Scenario - Second case: `C extends A with B` is not the same as `B extends A` + `C extends B`

Comment: Hi, I'm so sorry that I idiotically forgot to extends `A` in my second scenario code example, which misled me to the incorrect conclusion that class and trait behave differently in this context. I have updated the question description, hope it'll clarify.

Comment: The question is neither about differences between traits and abstract classes, nor about the differences between extends. It's about the effect that an abstract method has when it appears overridding the same concrete method of superclass.